# How to get the PHPLOC results displayed in Jenkins?

Tags: php, jenkins, static-code-analysis, code-metrics, lines-of-code

I use Jenkins for PHP projects with the [PHP Quality Assurance Toolchain](http://phpqatools.org/). To get the code analysis results displayed in Jenkins one simple has to add the according post-build action(-s):

[image: Jenkins-add-post-build-actions]

The problem is currently with the PHP QA tool [PHPLOC](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phploc). I don't find any possibility to add its reports to the project's / build's page.

**How to add the PHPLOC results to Jenkins (project and/or build page)?**

Answer (score 0):

use Plot plugin to process phploc.csv(xml)